# How to get/set a pandas index column title or name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I get the index column name in Python's pandas? Here's an example dataframe:

```
             Column 1
Index Title          
Apples              1
Oranges             2
Puppies             3
Ducks               4
```

What I'm trying to do is get/set the dataframe's index title. Here is what I tried:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Column 1'   : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 
        'Index Title': ["Apples", "Oranges", "Puppies", "Ducks"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index = df["Index Title"]
del df["Index Title"]
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 611, accepted):

You can just get/set the index via its `name` property

```
In [7]: df.index.name
Out[7]: 'Index Title'

In [8]: df.index.name = 'foo'

In [9]: df.index.name
Out[9]: 'foo'

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
         Column 1
foo              
Apples          1
Oranges         2
Puppies         3
Ducks           4
```

Comment: As of now (0.16) it does not work. Or rather - it does work, but as soon as DataFrame gets modifies, it erases index name.

Comment: it should be possible to specify index name at DataFrame creation time. e.g. `pd.DataFrame(values,index={"INDEX_NAME":index_values})`. I do not understand why this is not allowed or implemented?

Comment: you can directly construct with an Index to add a name

Comment: @Jeff, looks like your observation that constructing the index first (and use it for the dataframe's index and columns) is the correct approach although I concur with `@denfromufa` that it should take a dict as parameters to construct from pandas.DataFrame

Comment: If it is a Multiindex, use `df.index.names` instead of `df.index.name`.

Comment: To get rid of the index name, `df.index.name = None`.

Answer (score 130):

You can use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html), for removing set to `None`:

```
d = {'Index Title': ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Puppies', 'Ducks'],'Column 1': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index('Index Title')
print (df)
             Column 1
Index Title          
Apples            1.0
Oranges           2.0
Puppies           3.0
Ducks             4.0

print (df.index.name)
Index Title

print (df.columns.name)
None
```

---

The new functionality works well in method chains.

```
df = df.rename_axis('foo')
print (df)
         Column 1
foo              
Apples        1.0
Oranges       2.0
Puppies       3.0
Ducks         4.0
```

You can also rename column names with parameter `axis`:

```
d = {'Index Title': ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Puppies', 'Ducks'],'Column 1': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index('Index Title').rename_axis('Col Name', axis=1)
print (df)
Col Name     Column 1
Index Title          
Apples            1.0
Oranges           2.0
Puppies           3.0
Ducks             4.0

print (df.index.name)
Index Title

print (df.columns.name)
Col Name
```

```
print df.rename_axis('foo').rename_axis("bar", axis="columns")
bar      Column 1
foo              
Apples        1.0
Oranges       2.0
Puppies       3.0
Ducks         4.0

print df.rename_axis('foo').rename_axis("bar", axis=1)
bar      Column 1
foo              
Apples        1.0
Oranges       2.0
Puppies       3.0
Ducks         4.0
```

From version `pandas 0.24.0+` is possible use parameter `index` and `columns`:

```
df = df.rename_axis(index='foo', columns="bar")
print (df)
bar      Column 1
foo              
Apples        1.0
Oranges       2.0
Puppies       3.0
Ducks         4.0
```

Removing index and columns names means set it to `None`:

```
df = df.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
print (df)
         Column 1
Apples        1.0
Oranges       2.0
Puppies       3.0
Ducks         4.0
```

---

If `MultiIndex` in index only:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Puppies', 'Ducks'],
                                  list('abcd')], 
                                  names=['index name 1','index name 1'])


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(4,6)), 
                  index=mux, 
                  columns=list('ABCDEF')).rename_axis('col name', axis=1)
print (df)
col name                   A  B  C  D  E  F
index name 1 index name 1                  
Apples       a             5  4  0  5  2  2
Oranges      b             5  8  2  5  9  9
Puppies      c             7  6  0  7  8  3
Ducks        d             6  5  0  1  6  0
```

---

```
print (df.index.name)
None

print (df.columns.name)
col name

print (df.index.names)
['index name 1', 'index name 1']

print (df.columns.names)
['col name']
```

---

```
df1 = df.rename_axis(('foo','bar'))
print (df1)
col name     A  B  C  D  E  F
foo     bar                  
Apples  a    5  4  0  5  2  2
Oranges b    5  8  2  5  9  9
Puppies c    7  6  0  7  8  3
Ducks   d    6  5  0  1  6  0

df2 = df.rename_axis('baz', axis=1)
print (df2)
baz                        A  B  C  D  E  F
index name 1 index name 1                  
Apples       a             5  4  0  5  2  2
Oranges      b             5  8  2  5  9  9
Puppies      c             7  6  0  7  8  3
Ducks        d             6  5  0  1  6  0

df2 = df.rename_axis(index=('foo','bar'), columns='baz')
print (df2)
baz          A  B  C  D  E  F
foo     bar                  
Apples  a    5  4  0  5  2  2
Oranges b    5  8  2  5  9  9
Puppies c    7  6  0  7  8  3
Ducks   d    6  5  0  1  6  0
```

Removing index and columns names means set it to `None`:

```
df2 = df.rename_axis(index=(None,None), columns=None)
print (df2)

           A  B  C  D  E  F
Apples  a  6  9  9  5  4  6
Oranges b  2  6  7  4  3  5
Puppies c  6  3  6  3  5  1
Ducks   d  4  9  1  3  0  5
```

---

For `MultiIndex` in index and columns is necessary working with `.names` instead `.name` and set by list or tuples:

```
mux1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Puppies', 'Ducks'],
                                  list('abcd')], 
                                  names=['index name 1','index name 1'])


mux2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('ABC'),
                                  list('XY')], 
                                  names=['col name 1','col name 2'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(4,6)), index=mux1, columns=mux2)
print (df)
col name 1                 A     B     C   
col name 2                 X  Y  X  Y  X  Y
index name 1 index name 1                  
Apples       a             2  9  4  7  0  3
Oranges      b             9  0  6  0  9  4
Puppies      c             2  4  6  1  4  4
Ducks        d             6  6  7  1  2  8
```

Plural is necessary for check/set values:

```
print (df.index.name)
None

print (df.columns.name)
None

print (df.index.names)
['index name 1', 'index name 1']

print (df.columns.names)
['col name 1', 'col name 2']
```

---

```
df1 = df.rename_axis(('foo','bar'))
print (df1)
col name 1   A     B     C   
col name 2   X  Y  X  Y  X  Y
foo     bar                  
Apples  a    2  9  4  7  0  3
Oranges b    9  0  6  0  9  4
Puppies c    2  4  6  1  4  4
Ducks   d    6  6  7  1  2  8

df2 = df.rename_axis(('baz','bak'), axis=1)
print (df2)
baz                        A     B     C   
bak                        X  Y  X  Y  X  Y
index name 1 index name 1                  
Apples       a             2  9  4  7  0  3
Oranges      b             9  0  6  0  9  4
Puppies      c             2  4  6  1  4  4
Ducks        d             6  6  7  1  2  8

df2 = df.rename_axis(index=('foo','bar'), columns=('baz','bak'))
print (df2)
baz          A     B     C   
bak          X  Y  X  Y  X  Y
foo     bar                  
Apples  a    2  9  4  7  0  3
Oranges b    9  0  6  0  9  4
Puppies c    2  4  6  1  4  4
Ducks   d    6  6  7  1  2  8
```

Removing index and columns names means set it to `None`:

```
df2 = df.rename_axis(index=(None,None), columns=(None,None))
print (df2)

           A     B     C   
           X  Y  X  Y  X  Y
Apples  a  2  0  2  5  2  0
Oranges b  1  7  5  5  4  8
Puppies c  2  4  6  3  6  5
Ducks   d  9  6  3  9  7  0
```

And @Jeff solution:

```
df.index.names = ['foo','bar']
df.columns.names = ['baz','bak']
print (df)

baz          A     B     C   
bak          X  Y  X  Y  X  Y
foo     bar                  
Apples  a    3  4  7  3  3  3
Oranges b    1  2  5  8  1  0
Puppies c    9  6  3  9  6  3
Ducks   d    3  2  1  0  1  0
```

Comment: Also worth noting, as phil suggests in an other `df.index.rename('foo', inplace=True)` see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.rename.html#pandas.Index.rename

Comment: I have imported a dictionary to be used as a dataframe therefore the index column was set automatically to None with rows being numbered 1-10. But I would like to assign the "names" column as the index. And if possible do this during plotting. Is it possible to do this and is it possible to do this on the fly as we plot?

Comment: jezrael gave the right answer for the original question, which was about the column index names, not the row index names. Plus a complete explanation.  Basically, to Radical Edward have the index column name, just need to use df.index.names

Answer (score 33):

`df.index.name` should do the trick.

Python has a `dir` function that let's you query object attributes. `dir(df.index)` was helpful here.

Answer (score 22):

If you do not want to create a new row but simply put it in the empty cell then use:

```
df.columns.name = 'foo'
```

Otherwise use:

```
df.index.name = 'foo'
```

Comment: Just found it it's a name for columns' names. No wonder that setting df.index.name gives you a new level. Thank you!

Answer (score 22):

Use `df.index.rename('foo', inplace=True)` to set the index name.

Seems this api is available since [pandas 0.13](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.0/generated/pandas.Index.rename.html#pandas.Index.rename).

Comment: Wow... an elegant solution!

Comment: currently better not to use `inplace` as it's going to be deprecated, but otherwise good

Answer (score 16):

Setting the index name can also be accomplished at creation:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={'age': [10,20,30], 'height': [100, 170, 175]}, index=pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'], name='Tag'))
```

Comment: `RangeIndex` also works `df = pd.DataFrame(..., index=pd.RangeIndex(10, name='No'))`

Answer (score 6):

`df.columns.values` also give us the column names

Answer (score 4):

The solution for multi-indexes is inside jezrael's cyclopedic answer, but it took me a while to find it so I am posting a new answer:

`df.index.names` gives the names of a multi-index (as a Frozenlist).

Answer (score 2):

To just get the index column names `df.index.names` will work for both a single Index or MultiIndex as of the most recent version of pandas.

As someone who found this while trying to find the best way to get a list of index names + column names, I would have found this answer useful:

```
names = list(filter(None, df.index.names + df.columns.values.tolist()))
```

This works for no index, single column Index, or MultiIndex. It avoids calling reset_index() which has an unnecessary performance hit for such a simple operation. I'm surprised there isn't a built in method for this (that I've come across). I guess I run into needing this more often because I'm shuttling data from databases where the dataframe index maps to a primary/unique key, but is really just another column to me.

Answer (score 2):

###### 1. Use `pd.Index` to name an index (or column) from construction

Pandas has `Index` (`MultiIndex`) objects that accepts names. Passing those as index or column on dataframe construction constructs frames with named indices/columns.

```py
data = {'Column 1': [1,2,3,4], 'Index Title': ["Apples","Oranges","Puppies","Ducks"]}

# for RangeIndex
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.Index(range(4), name='foo'))
#                             ^^^^^^^^  <---- here

# for Index
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.Index(data['Index Title'], name='foo'))
#                             ^^^^^^^^  <---- here

# for columns
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=pd.Index(data.keys(), name='foo'))
#                               ^^^^^^^^  <---- here

# for MultiIndex
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Animal', 'Animal'], data['Index Title']], names=['foo', 'bar']))
#                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  <---- here
```

###### 2. Change MultiIndex level name

If the dataframe has MultiIndex and an index name at a specific level has to be changed, `index.set_names` may be used. For example, to change the name of the second index level, use the following. Don't forget `inplace=True`.

```py
df.index.set_names('foo', level=1, inplace=True)

# equivalently, rename could be used with a dict
df.index.rename({'Index Title 2': 'foo'}, inplace=True)
```

[image: res1]

---

`set_names` can also be used for just regular index (set `level=None`). However, `rename_axis` is probably easier.

```py
df.index.set_names('foo', level=None, inplace=True)

# equivalent to the following
df.index.name = 'foo'
df = df.rename_axis('foo')
```

[image: res2]

---

There's a corresponding `columns.set_names` for columns.

```py
df.columns.set_names('foo', level=None, inplace=True)
# equivalent to 
df = df.rename_axis(columns='foo')

# for MultiIndex columns
df.columns.set_names('foo', level=0, inplace=True)
```

[image: res3]