# Rename Pandas DataFrame Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I've a csv file without header, with a DateTime index. I want to rename the index and column name, but with df.rename() only the column name is renamed. Bug? I'm on version 0.12.0

```
In [2]: df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\Data\DataTimeSeries_csv//seriesSM.csv', header=None, parse_dates=[[0]], index_col=[0] )

In [3]: df.head()
Out[3]: 
                   1
0                   
2002-06-18  0.112000
2002-06-22  0.190333
2002-06-26  0.134000
2002-06-30  0.093000
2002-07-04  0.098667

In [4]: df.rename(index={0:'Date'}, columns={1:'SM'}, inplace=True)

In [5]: df.head()
Out[5]: 
                  SM
0                   
2002-06-18  0.112000
2002-06-22  0.190333
2002-06-26  0.134000
2002-06-30  0.093000
2002-07-04  0.098667
```

Comment: i swear in 2022 I still look up this question like 4 times a month.

Comment: Don't worry man! I am at the end of 2022 and I do the same -_-.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18022845).

Answer (score 425, accepted):

The `rename` method takes a dictionary for the index which applies to index *values*.
You want to rename to index level's name:

```
df.index.names = ['Date']
```

*A good way to think about this is that columns and index are the same type of object (`Index` or `MultiIndex`), and you can interchange the two via transpose.*

This is a little bit confusing since the index names have a similar meaning to columns, so here are some more examples:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5 ,6]], columns=list('ABC'))

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

In [3]: df1 = df.set_index('A')

In [4]: df1
Out[4]: 
   B  C
A      
1  2  3
4  5  6
```

You can see the rename on the index, which can change the *value* 1:

```
In [5]: df1.rename(index={1: 'a'})
Out[5]: 
   B  C
A      
a  2  3
4  5  6

In [6]: df1.rename(columns={'B': 'BB'})
Out[6]: 
   BB  C
A       
1   2  3
4   5  6
```

Whilst renaming the level names:

```
In [7]: df1.index.names = ['index']
        df1.columns.names = ['column']
```

Note: this attribute is just a list, and you could do the renaming as a list comprehension/map.

```
In [8]: df1
Out[8]: 
column  B  C
index       
1       2  3
4       5  6
```

Comment: Great answer.  Just a gentle reminder that without `"inplace =True"`, `df1.rename` would not really change anything.

Comment: @Sarah why did that magical line you mentioned make the change?

Comment: Inplace modifies the already existing pandas data frame object. While the operation without inplace leaves the data frame untouched and returns a newly created df. 

Therefore without rename one must do something like this: df1 = df1.rename....

Comment: Why is this answer at the bottom? The ones above it don't work. This answer clearly has the most votes.

Comment: If it's not a multiindex, you can use `df.index.name = "name"`, without surrounding the entry in a list.

Answer (score 124):

The currently selected answer does not mention the `rename_axis` method which can be used to rename the index and column levels.

---

Pandas has some quirkiness when it comes to renaming the levels of the index. There is also a new DataFrame method **`rename_axis`** available to change the index level names.

Let's take a look at a DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':[30, 2, 12],
                       'color':['blue', 'green', 'red'],
                       'food':['Steak', 'Lamb', 'Mango'],
                       'height':[165, 70, 120],
                       'score':[4.6, 8.3, 9.0],
                       'state':['NY', 'TX', 'FL']},
                       index = ['Jane', 'Nick', 'Aaron'])
```

[image]

This DataFrame has one level for each of the row and column indexes. Both the row and column index have no name. Let's change the row index level name to 'names'.

```
df.rename_axis('names')
```

[image]

The `rename_axis` method also has the ability to change the column level names by changing the `axis` parameter:

```
df.rename_axis('names').rename_axis('attributes', axis='columns')
```

[image]

If you set the index with some of the columns, then the column name will become the new index level name. Let's append to index levels to our original DataFrame:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['state', 'color'], append=True)
df1
```

[image]

Notice how the original index has no name. We can still use `rename_axis` but need to pass it a list the same length as the number of index levels.

```
df1.rename_axis(['names', None, 'Colors'])
```

[image]

You can use `None` to effectively delete the index level names.

---

#### Series work similarly but with some differences

Let's create a Series with three index levels

```
s = df.set_index(['state', 'color'], append=True)['food']
s

       state  color
Jane   NY     blue     Steak
Nick   TX     green     Lamb
Aaron  FL     red      Mango
Name: food, dtype: object
```

We can use `rename_axis` similarly to how we did with DataFrames

```
s.rename_axis(['Names','States','Colors'])

Names  States  Colors
Jane   NY      blue      Steak
Nick   TX      green      Lamb
Aaron  FL      red       Mango
Name: food, dtype: object
```

Notice that the there is an extra piece of metadata below the Series called `Name`. When creating a Series from a DataFrame, this attribute is set to the column name.

We can pass a string name to the `rename` method to change it

```
s.rename('FOOOOOD')

       state  color
Jane   NY     blue     Steak
Nick   TX     green     Lamb
Aaron  FL     red      Mango
Name: FOOOOOD, dtype: object
```

DataFrames do not have this attribute and infact will raise an exception if used like this

```
df.rename('my dataframe')
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Prior to pandas 0.21, you could have used `rename_axis` to rename the values in the index and columns. It has been deprecated so don't do this

Comment: Should you swap `df1 = df.set_index(['state', 'color'], append=True)` with `df1.rename_axis(['names', None, 'Colors'])`?

Comment: What if I want to rename "Nick" to "Nicolas"? That was what I was looking for when I googled "rename pandas index" and ended up here. EDIT: Oh wait, the accepted answer does explain that, it just wasn't obvious to me at first.

Comment: Nice, this is the only answer that can be used in chained assignments!

Comment: There's no need to call it twice when renaming both the index and columns, you can take care of it once with the args: `df.rename_axis(index='names', columns='attributes')`

Answer (score 47):

## For newer `pandas` versions

```
df.index = df.index.rename('new name')
```

or

```
df.index.rename('new name', inplace=True)
```

**The latter is required** if a data frame should retain all its properties.

Answer (score 21):

In Pandas version 0.13 and greater the index level names are immutable (type `FrozenList`) and can no longer be set directly.  You must first use `Index.rename()` to apply the new index level names to the Index and then use `DataFrame.reindex()` to apply the new index to the DataFrame.  Examples:

**For Pandas version < 0.13**

```
df.index.names = ['Date']
```

**For Pandas version >= 0.13**

```
df = df.reindex(df.index.rename(['Date']))
```

Comment: Not true! In my version of Pandas (0.13.1) df.index.names = ['foo'] works fine!

Comment: Thanks for noticing that @LondonRob - ` df.index.names = ['foo']` also works for me with Pandas 0.14.  Apparently that was only broken briefly and included when I tested it.

Comment: Setting names for either `index` or `column` directly is changing both for me (on Pandas 0.19), but not with this method.

Answer (score 11):

For Single Index :

```
 df.index.rename('new_name')
```

For Multi Index :

```
 df.index.rename(['new_name','new_name2'])
```

WE can also use this in latest pandas :

[rename_axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)

Comment: If you do that you will just have a renamed index as a return but the data frame will not be changed.

Comment: `df.index.rename('new_name', inplace=True)` modifies the dataframe in place.

Comment: FWIW, you can also use a mapper with `rename` and `set_names`. `df.index.rename({'old_name': 'new_name')`.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use [`Index.set_names`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.set_names.html) as follows:

```
In [25]: x = pd.DataFrame({'year':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
   ....:                   'country':['A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B'],
   ....:                   'prod':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
   ....:                   'val':[10,20,15,25,20,30,25,35]})

In [26]: x = x.set_index(['year','country','prod']).squeeze()

In [27]: x
Out[27]: 
year  country  prod
1     A        1       10
               2       20
      B        1       15
               2       25
2     A        1       20
               2       30
      B        1       25
               2       35
Name: val, dtype: int64
In [28]: x.index = x.index.set_names('foo', level=1)

In [29]: x
Out[29]: 
year  foo  prod
1     A    1       10
           2       20
      B    1       15
           2       25
2     A    1       20
           2       30
      B    1       25
           2       35
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `index` and `columns` attributes of `pandas.DataFrame`. NOTE: number of elements of list must match the number of rows/columns.

```
#       A   B   C
# ONE   11  12  13
# TWO   21  22  23
# THREE 31  32  33

df.index = [1, 2, 3]
df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(df)

#     a   b   c
# 1  11  12  13
# 2  21  22  23
# 3  31  32  33
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the same mapping for renaming both columns and index you can do:

```
mapping = {0:'Date', 1:'SM'}
df.index.names = list(map(lambda name: mapping.get(name, name), df.index.names))
df.rename(columns=mapping, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.index.rename('new name', inplace=True)
```

Is the only one that does the job for me (pandas 0.22.0).
Without the inplace=True, the name of the index is not set in my case.