# Python Pandas Dataframe Set specific datetime row label to string in index?

Tags: python, datetime, indexing, pandas, dataframe

**My Pandas dataframe code**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Impressions': [92964, 91282, 88143,272389], 'Clicks': [3128, 3131, 2580, 8839]}, index=pd.to_datetime(['6/1/2015', '6/8/2015', '6/15/2015', '1/1/2020']))
df.index.name = 'Date'
```

**Produces**

```
            Clicks  Impressions
Date                           
2015-06-01    3128        92964
2015-06-08    3131        91282
2015-06-15    2580        88143
2020-01-01    8839       272389
```

How can I change the `2020-01-01` to be a string that says `Total`?

**What I want to achieve is this:**

```
            Clicks  Impressions
Date                           
2015-06-01    3128        92964
2015-06-08    3131        91282
2015-06-15    2580        88143
Total         8839       272389
```

**More context**
`df.index.dtype` is of datatype `dtype('<M8[ns]')`
I think I can access the index row label by this `df.index[-1]` which tells me it's a `Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')`.

But if I try to do something like this, it does not work:
`df.index[-1] = 'Total'`

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    df.index[-1] = 'Total'
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 922, in __setitem__
    raise TypeError("Indexes does not support mutable operations")
TypeError: Indexes does not support mutable operations
```

Comment: This post seems to have what you are looking for: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851005/rename-pandas-dataframe-index

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Ultimately, `df.rename(index={df.index[-1]: 'Total'})` did change the index value to `Total` on this sample data I posted in my question.  But, when I attempt to use it in my primary app I'm working on, it didn't work for me.  I think @bleh is right on that the issue is handling multiple data types in the same array.  Thanks nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do that:

```
In [154]: %paste
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Impressions': [92964, 91282, 88143,272389], 'Clicks': [3128, 3131, 2580, 8839]}, index=pd.to_datetime(['6/1/2015', '6/8/2015', '6/15/2015', '1/1/2020']))
df.index.name = 'Date'

## -- End pasted text --

In [155]: df = df.reset_index()

In [156]: df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(object)

In [157]: df['Date'] = df.Date.dt.date

In [158]: df.ix[3,0] = 'Total'

In [159]: df.index = df.Date

In [160]: df.drop(['Date'], axis=1, inplace=True)

In [161]: df
Out[161]: 
            Clicks  Impressions
Date                           
2015-06-01    3128        92964
2015-06-08    3131        91282
2015-06-15    2580        88143
Total         8839       272389
```

The issue is trying to handle multiple data types in the same array. You need to cast the series into an `object` type.

Answer (score 0):

Couple years later, in hindsight, I was approaching this problem without knowing that Pandas pivot table has a `margins` parameter which can add a label like `"total"` and provide the sum totals row.

```
df.head(3).pivot_table(['Impressions', 'Clicks'], index=df.index[:-1],
                       aggfunc='sum', margins=True, margins_name='Total')

                     Clicks  Impressions
Date                                    
2015-06-01 00:00:00    3128        92964
2015-06-08 00:00:00    3131        91282
2015-06-15 00:00:00    2580        88143
Total                  8839       272389
```

But to more accurately answer the question of "**How to assign a specific label to a datetime index at a certain row**", you basically can't because the entire index is a datatype of `DatetimeIndex` so all elements need to be this type.

To get around this fact, you can do this:

```
idx = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
idx.values[-1] = 'Total'
df.index = idx
```

Result

```
            Impressions  Clicks
2015-06-01        92964    3128
2015-06-08        91282    3131
2015-06-15        88143    2580
Total            272389    8839
```