# how to change index name in pandas?

Tags: dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'name': ['wang','xiao','lin','du','cui'], 'chi': [82,93,75,97,85],'py':[86,94,86,68,98]} 
frame1=pd.DataFrame(data1)
print(frame1)
```

how can I change the default index 0 1 2 3 4 into a b c d e? 
Please advise me about this, thanks.

Comment: This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851005/rename-pandas-dataframe-index).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename Pandas DataFrame Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851005/rename-pandas-dataframe-index)

Comment: Have you read this post: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851005/rename-pandas-dataframe-index)

Answer (score 0):

To change the values of index from `0 1 2 3 4` into `a b c d e` use:

```
frame1.index = list('abcde')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.