# Pandas rename index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe, where I want to rename the index from`summary` to `id`:

```
summary  student  count 
0        error    6
1        yes      1
2        no       1
3        other    9
```

I have tried:
`newdf = df.reset_index().rename(columns={df.index.name:'foo'})` which gives:

```
summary  index    student  count    
0        0        error   6
1        1        yes     1
2        2        no      1
3        3        other   9
```

I have also tried: `df.index.rename('foo', inplace = True)` which gives:

```
 summary     student  count
 foo        
 0           error    6
 1           yes      1
 2           no       1
 3           other    9
```

I have also tried: `df.rename_axis('why', inplace = True)` which gives:

```
 summary     student  count
 why        
 0           error    6
 1           yes      1
 2           no       1
 3           other    9
```

When I do `df.dtypes`:

```
summary
student object
count   init64
dtype:  object
```

What I would like:

```
id  student  count 
0   error    6
1   yes      1
2   no       1
3   other    9
```

OR:

```
    student  count 
0   error    6
1   yes      1
2   no       1
3   other    9
```

Comment: This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851005/rename-pandas-dataframe-index

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to remove the column name:

```
df.rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename_axis('id', axis=0)
##if pd.__version__ == 0.24.0 
#df.rename_axis([None], axis=1).rename_axis('id')
```

---

The problem is that `'summary'` is your column name. When there is no index name, the column name is placed directly above the index, which can be misleading:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1]*2]*4, columns=['A', 'B'])
df.columns.name = 'col_name'
print(df)

#col_name  A  B
#0         1  1
#1         1  1
#2         1  1
#3         1  1
```

When you then try to add an index name, it becomes clear that `'col_name'` was really the column name.

```
df.index.name = 'idx_name'
print(df)

#col_name  A  B
#idx_name      
#0         1  1
#1         1  1
#2         1  1
#3         1  1
```

There is no ambiguity though: when you have an index name, the columns are raised one level, which allows you to distinguish between an index name and a column name.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1]*2]*4, columns=['A', 'B'])
df.index.name = 'idx_name'
print(df)

#          A  B
#idx_name      
#0         1  1
#1         1  1
#2         1  1
#3         1  1
```

Answer (score 5):

you need to access the index's properties

```
df.index.name = 'id'
```

original

```
         student  count
summary               
0         error      6
1           yes      1
2            no      1
3         other      9
```

fixed df:

```
    student  count
id               
0    error      6
1      yes      1
2       no      1
3    other      9
```

Update: seems like you had a name for the column's index. You should remove it with

`df.columns.names = ''`

Comment: `df.index.name = 'id'` adds `id` in addition to `summary` rather than renaming `summary`. Not sure what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

First you can drop the column:

```
df = df.drop('summary', axis=1)
df['id'] = np.arange(df.shape[0])
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
```

Then you can get the desired result.