# Python Dataframe First Column Offset

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I'm using a python to call an API and load it to a data frame, pretty simple code:

```
import simfin as sf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Set your SimFin+ API-key for downloading data.
sf.set_api_key('free')

# Set the local directory where data-files are stored.
# The directory will be created if it does not already exist.
sf.set_data_dir('~/simfin_data/')

df_industries = sf.load_industries()

print(df_industries)
```

The problem is the output has the first column header offset and when I load this data into powerBI it ignores the first column:

```
                     Sector                    Industry
IndustryId
100001          Industrials         Industrial Products
100002          Industrials           Business Services
100003          Industrials  Engineering & Construction
100004          Industrials            Waste Management
100005          Industrials     Industrial Distribution
...                     ...                         ...
110004      Basic Materials             Metals & Mining
110005      Basic Materials          Building Materials
110006      Basic Materials                        Coal
110007      Basic Materials                       Steel
111001                Other        Diversified Holdings
```

How should I get that first column in the same alignment as the other columns which should make it import into powerBI properly.

Comment: The first thing you think is a column is really the `Index` with the name `'IndustryId'`. Just do `df = df.reset_index()`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55027108/pandas-rename-index/55028542#55028542 is an example that shows you the placement of index and column names (the last example with just a named index is what you have here).

Comment: Got it, thank you! Works perfectly.