# How to drop level of column in Pandas when the second level is in the first column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data

```
   ---+--
    b | c
--+---+--
a
--+---+-- 
0 | 1 | 2
1 | 3 | 4
```

I would like to drop the level of column a and have the following as output:

```
--+---+--
 a| b | c
--+---+--
0 | 1 | 2
1 | 3 | 4
```

I have tried `df.droplevel(1)` but got the following error:

```
IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have a simple Index on the columns, but have a named Index, so it is displayed that way. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55028542/4333359 that illustrates things are displayed when the row or columns index has a name. It allows you to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: from the way you printed here, it looks more that a is the index, so `df.reset_index()` would kind of do what you want. to be sure, can you edit your question with the result of `print(df.index)` and `print(df.columns)`

Comment: @Ben.T : The out put for print(df.index) is Index([0,1]) and print(df.columns) is index(['b', 'c'])

Comment: @Ben.T : My apologies: The output for print(df.index) is Index(['0','1'], dtype=dtype='object', name='a')

Comment: so yes, I recommend go through the link provided by @ALollz in their comment, and as a is actually your index name, then you can either `rename_axis(None)` to make it disappeared or use `reset_index` such as `a` become a column and the display will be better :)

Comment: @ben-t : tried both `reset_index` and `rename_axis`, none of them is working. Getting same output.

Comment: hmmm do you reassign it? if you `print( df.reset_index())` it does not work? what about `df = df.reset_index()` and then print df?

Comment: @Ben.T - Thanks Ben! reassigning the df, solved the problem.

Comment: @alollz - Thanks, your solution and Ben's help solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Alollz & @Ben, I did the following:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

And got the following output

```
---+---+---+---+
   | a | b | c
---+---+---+---+--
 0 | 0 | 1 | 2
 1 | 1 | 3 | 4
```

Comment: Good idea to answer your question, you can also accept it to help the management of the site :)