# make index column name and values column name in one level

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I need the index column name and the value column name to be on the same level:

`index name | values column name`

DataFrame:
[image: dataframe]

My code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(aqi_val_dct, orient='index', columns=['Индекс качества воздуха (AQI)'])
df.index.name = 'Станция'
print(df)
```

Comment: That's now how it works in pandas.... It's differentiated that way you can always distinguish between a name on the row index, a name on the column index, and column labels: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55028542/4333359

Comment: @ALollz, thank you!

df.columns.name = 'Станция' - that helped!

Comment: Yes that would be one way to  get it where you want, though if it's truly a label for the index values, and not columns, naming the columns could become misleading.

Comment: Because your question is related to formatting and style: What environment and what output are you using, where do you need this style? Is it HTML and for jupyterlab?