# Best way to set index name in Python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, set

When creating a blank dataframe in Pandas there appears to be at least 2 ways to set the index name.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1',  'col2'])
df.index.name = 'index name'



df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['index name', 'col1',  'col2'])
df.set_index('index name', inplace=True)
```

Is one preferred over the other? Is there a third way to do it in 1 line of code instead of 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename Pandas DataFrame Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851005/rename-pandas-dataframe-index)

Comment: `df.rename_axis('index name', axis='index', inplace=True)`

Comment: Or `df.index = df.index.rename('index name')` or `df.index.rename('index name', inplace=True)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think here is best use [method chaining](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#methodchaining):

> The pandas core team now encourages the use of **method chaining**. This is a style of programming in which you chain together multiple method calls into a single statement. This allows you to pass intermediate results from one method to the next rather than storing the intermediate results using variables.

Another soution [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1',  'col2']).rename_axis('index name')
```

Or change your second solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['index name', 'col1',  'col2']).set_index('index name')
```

---

`inplace` is not recommended - [link](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace):

> The pandas core team discourages the use of the **inplace** parameter, and eventually it will be deprecated (which means "scheduled for removal from the library"). Here's why:
>
> **inplace** won't work within a method chain.
> The use of **inplace** often doesn't prevent copies from being created, contrary to what the name implies.
> Removing the **inplace** option would reduce the complexity of the pandas codebase.