# How do i name my index column of the attached dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t91Gb.png)Please i am trying to name the index column but I can't. I want to be a able to name it such that I can reference it to view the index values which are dates. i have tried

df3.rename(columns={0:'Date'}, inplace=True) but it's not working.

Please can someone help me out? Thank you.

Comment: please show an example of your dataframe and try df=df.rename(index={0:'Date'})

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename Pandas DataFrame Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851005/rename-pandas-dataframe-index)

Comment: sorry, i attached a picture but just realized that it wasnt attached to my question. I have edited it.

Comment: `df=df.rename_axis(index='Date')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the dataframe index cannot be accessed using `df['Date']`,

I fyou want rename the index, you can use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df=df.rename_axis(index='Date')
```

---

if you want to access it as a column then you have to transform it into a column using:

```
df=df.reset_index()
```

then you can use:

```
df['Date']
```

otherwise you can access the index by:

```
df.index
```

Comment: Thank you very much. df=df.rename_axis(index='Date') worked for me. I so much appreciate.@ansev

Answer (score 0):

As there is no example data frame that you are on, I am listing an arbitrary example to demonstrate the idea.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

data = {'C1'     : [1, 2],
        'Date'  : [dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index = df["Date"]
del df["Date"]

print(df.index.name) # this will give you the new index column

print(df) #print the dataframe
```

[image]