# How to rename dataframe index efficiently using a python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rename

I have a pandas dataframe and a ordered list like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5 ,6]], columns=list('ABC'))
df = df.rename(index={0:'x1'})
df = df.rename(index={1:'x2'})
```

[image]

Please note that I already refer [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851005/rename-pandas-dataframe-index)

The list looks like as shown below

```
ordered_list = ['Name_1','Name_2']
```

This is what I was trying but it is not efficient and cannot be used for a dataframe with more records

```
df = df.rename(index={'x1':'Name_1'})
df = df.rename(index={'x2':'Name_2'})
```

You can see that I have renamed the index using `rename` function. But **is there anyway to do this efficiently using the `ordered list` available?** Because my real data has `more than 60 index values`

I mean first element in the list corresponds to `x1` and 2nd element in the list corresponds to `x2` etc.

I expect my output to look like as shown below

[image]

Comment: `df.index = ordered_list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
df.index = ordered_list
```

Comment: @SSMK No problem

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, then you wont need an ordered list:

```
df.index = df.reset_index().index+1
df = df.T.add_prefix('Name_').T
```