# Merge 2 dataframes make sure index is there for left dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, merge

I have two dataframes:
`df_transactions` & `df_custdemo`

I want to merge the two on `df_transactions`. (i.e. all the customer demographics data should merge onto the transactions data).
The merge is done on `customer_id`, however the index for `df_transactions = transaction_id.`

When I merge, the final table result does not have the `transaction_id` column. How can i merge to also get that?

I have tried:

```py
df_custdemo_transactions = df_transactions.merge(df_custdemo, how='left', left_on='customer_id', right_on='customer_id', left_index=True)
```

and

```py
df_custdemo_transactions = df_transactions.merge(df_custdemo, how='left', left_on='customer_id', right_on='customer_id')
```

But final result does not have the transaction_id yet.

Comment: Have you tried df_custdemo_transactions.reset_index(inplace=True)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line before the executing the merge statement.

```
 df_transactions.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! - how can rename the index to be transaction_id?

Comment: You can check this link ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851005/rename-pandas-dataframe-index) on how to rename indexes.

Comment: Or to be more specific to ur question. After the merge, add this line `df_transactions.set_index('transaction_id',inplace = True)`