# Must pass an index to rename - python

Tags: python, indexing, rename

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

I want to rename the columns to snake case using a function I defined:

```
def to_snakecase(cols):
map_dict = {}
for col in cols:
    map_dict[col] = col.lower().strip().replace(' ', '_')
```

When I write the code:

```
covid_df.rename(to_snakecase(covid_df.columns), axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I get the error: `must pass an index to rename`

I have looked at the documentation but haven't figured it out. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: this  should help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851005/rename-pandas-dataframe-index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your function returns `None` and rename function cannot find Indexer

```
def to_snakecase(cols):
    map_dict = {}
    for col in cols:
        map_dict[col] = col.lower().strip().replace(' ', '_')
    return map_dict
```

I belive that the most expresive way to rename columns is  to use keyword `columns` in `rename` function.
Your code could look as follows

```
covid_df.rename(columns=to_snakecase(covid_df.columns), inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you Marek. The problem was that the function returned None, therefore there was no index in the first place. Thank you