# How to set column name to Index in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataset and I wanted to set Column name for the index also. How can we set Column name for Index column? Assume, I want to set it as "State"

```
    confirmed  deceased  recovered    tested
AN       7557       129       7420         0
AP    2003342     13735    1975448   9788047
AR      52214       259      50695    398545
AS     584434      5576     570847    326318
BR     725588      9649     715798  17107895
CH      65068       812      64220    654348
CT    1004144     13553     989728    338344
DL    1437334     25079    1411881  25142853
DN      10662         4      10620     72410
GA     173221      3186     169160         0
GJ     825302     10079     815041  10900176
HP     211979      3558     206366    481328
HR     770362      9668     760026   3948145
JH     347730      5132     342421    233773
JK     324295      4403     318838    139552
KA    2939767     37155    2882331   9791334
KL    3814305     19494    3631066   3875002
LA      20491       207      20223    110068
LD      10317        51      10197    234256
MH    6428294    136067    6238794   8421643
ML      74070      1281      69859         0
MN     111212      1755     105751     13542
MP     792104     10516     781504   3384824
MZ      52472       200      46675         0
NL      29622       610      27238    116359
OR    1001698      7479     986334   2774807
PB     600266     16352     583426   2938477
PY     122934      1808     120330    567923
RJ     954030      8954     944917   5852578
SK      29340       367      27185         0
TG     655343      3861     645174         0
TN    2602489     34734    2548868   4413963
TR      82092       784      80150    607962
TT          0         0          0         0
UP    1709126     22792    1685972  23724581
UT     342771      7377     329030   2127358
WB    1543496     18371    1515789         0
```

Comment: Check the Answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851005/rename-pandas-dataframe-index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.rename_axis('State')
```

Or:

```
df.rename_axis('State', inplace=True)
```

If you further want the index as column:

```
df = df.rename_axis('State').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

`df.index.name = "State"`