# Change Index and Reindex Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I have a Python dictionary and I created a panda data frame like below:

[image]

I want to change the name of index column to `date` . But I couldn't do this with `data.set_index('date')` . How can I do this? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `df.rename_axis('date')`, since date is already in index, you're probably looking to name the index.

Comment: Or `df.index.name = 'date'`

Comment: See [Pandas index column title or name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022845/pandas-index-column-title-or-name)

Comment: hmmm, good link, but very old. Your is better.

Comment: @jezrael "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" because the index in None

Comment: @TheNone - Interesting, for me it working.

Comment: @TheNone - If use some old version of pandas, `df.rename_axis('date')` should failed.

Comment: @jezrael how can I reindex by int?

Comment: @TheNone - Not sure if understand - `int` are days? Or something else?

Comment: @jezrael   this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504357/change-a-pandas-dataframe-with-integer-index

Answer (score 0):

`data.set_index('date')` here only assign the column with name 'date' as index for the dataframe `data`.

You can rewrite the name of the column using `data.index.name = 'data'`