# Change a Pandas DataFrame with Integer Index

Tags: pandas

I have converted a Python dict to pandas dataframe:

```
dict = {
         u'erterreherh': 
                  {
                    u'account': u'rgrgrgrg',
                    u'data': u'192.168.1.1', 

                  }, 
         u'hkghkghkghk': 
                 {
                   u'account': u'uououopuopuop', 
                   u'data': '192.168.1.170', 
                 }, 
        }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient='index')



account data
aa      bbss
zz      sssss
vv      sss
```

"account" is index here. I want to dataframe like below, how can I do this?

```
    account data
   0   aa      bbss
   1   zz      sssss
   2   vv      ss
```

Comment: Use  `df = df.reset_index()` I think

Comment: This is so basic question. @TheNone Sir search once before asking the quesiton.

Comment: I tried this. df.reset_index() not works

Comment: Did you assign it to dataframe variable?

Comment: OK, what means does not work? If use it, what happans?

Comment: @Bharathshetty yes, "account" is index, I want to reindex to integere

Comment: @TheNone that is no reindex ... it is reset_index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for change index name and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
d = {
         u'erterreherh': 
                  {
                    u'account': u'rgrgrgrg',
                    u'data': u'192.168.1.1'

                  }, 
         u'hkghkghkghk': 
                 {
                   u'account': u'uououopuopuop', 
                   u'data': '192.168.1.170' 
                 } 
        }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
df = df.rename_axis('acount1').reset_index()
print (df)
       acount1           data        account
0  erterreherh    192.168.1.1       rgrgrgrg
1  hkghkghkghk  192.168.1.170  uououopuopuop
```

If need overwrite column `account` by values from `index`:

```
df = df.assign(account=df.index).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
            data      account
0    192.168.1.1  erterreherh
1  192.168.1.170  hkghkghkghk
```

Comment: I convert a dict python to pandas dataframe. with "df.rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename_axis('account').reset_index()" account and data added to the same column

Comment: So still is problem? I add to my answer `df = pd.DataFrame({'data': ['bbss', 'sssss', 'sss']}, index=['aa','zz','vv'])` for better explanation. What is `print (df.info())` of your rela data? Maybe it help understand your problem.

Comment: OK, please check my answer. Or do you need overwrite column `account` by `index` values ?

Comment: I'm very confused. len(df.columns) is 1

Comment: @TheNone - I have an idea - can you send me your data (anonymize if confidental) with your code to my email? I believe there has to be some data problem - no idea without your real data.

Answer (score 1):

`df.reset_index()` is indeed working for me.

```
df
```

```
          data
account       
aa        bbss
zz       sssss
vv         sss
```

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

```
  account   data
0      aa   bbss
1      zz  sssss
2      vv    sss
```

Comment: when I try reset_index, I have "account" and "data" in same column

Comment: what does df.columns after reseting index return?

Comment: can you add df.columns before and after ?