# Title to index column doesn't remain - Python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, indexing

I'm given a dataframe, to which I wish to add a title on the indexing column. I've done this:

```
test_set = pd.read_csv('test_set.csv')
df= pd.DataFrame(data = test_set)
df.to_csv('test_set2.csv', encoding='utf-8')
df.index.rename('indexTitle', inplace=True)
```

If I print this test_set now, it's got the title on the index column.
But in the end the file doesn't display with the title; the change isn't saved in the file. I know I can add the title manually but would like to know if there's a way to do so through my code.

It prints this:

```
                                               data
indexTitle                                                   
0       data0...
1       data1...
2       data2...
...
```

I'm using Python 2.7, pandas 0.22

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas index column title or name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022845/pandas-index-column-title-or-name)

Comment: I've seen this (alongside numerous other questions on this site) but they didn't do what I'm trying to do here (to my understanding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `df.index.rename('indexTitle', inplace=True)` line I added this:
`df.to_csv('test_set2.csv', encoding='utf-8')` which updated the file I had.