# How to identify the index column in a data frame python / pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Really basic question for a new programmer - I've created a new data frame by merging 2 of them, and I want to identify the index in the newly created data frame.

More generally, if I create or upload a new data frame, is there a quick way to check which column (location or name) is the current index?

Comment: You can access the current index by `df.index`. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022845/pandas-index-column-title-or-name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas index column title or name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022845/pandas-index-column-title-or-name)