# Pandas dataframe column with title 'name'

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple dataframes which I join based on a common column. The code looks like this:

```
df=reduce(lambda x,y:pd.merge(x,y,on='name'),[total,eliminated, actionable, bug])
```

Afterwards, I intend to rename the column `name`. But `name` is not anymore in the column list. When I print the `df`, the name column shows but I don't know how to work with that merged column anymore, like renaming.

If I print `type(df), df.columns, df`, it shows:

```
(pandas.core.frame.DataFrame,
 Index(['total', 'e', 'a', 'b'], dtype='object'),
                        total      e      a      b
 name                                             
 !CHAOS Control System    282  80.14  39.01   1.42
 Chromium EC              306  93.46  29.74  17.65
 Firefox                 5448  77.22  49.72  12.43
```

What happended to the `name` column and how can I rename it afterwards?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022845/pandas-index-column-title-or-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you set 'name' as the index. Try this:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```