# How to convert index and values to a proper dataframe with callable column names? Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on this dataset where I have used the `sort_values()` function to get two distinct columns: the `index` and the `values`. I can even rename the index and the values columns. However, if I rename the dataset columns and assign everything to a new dataframe, I am not able to call the index column with the name that I assigned to it earlier.

```
pm_freq = df["payment_method"].value_counts()
pm_freq = pm_freq.head().to_frame()
pm_freq.index.name="Method"
pm_freq.rename(columns={"payment_method":"Frequency"},inplace=True)
pm_freq
```

Now I want to call it like this:

```
pm_freq["Method"]
```

But there's an error which states:

> " KeyError: 'Method'"

Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Here, `Method` is your `index` not a `column`. Do: `pm_freq.reset_index()["Method"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the comment here, not sure if still correct:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18023468/15600610

Comment: This is not what OP is looking for. Also, please don't post answers, until you are very sure.